# How to avoid Duplicate finish request for ActivityRecord

Tags: android, android-activity

From LoginActivity after successful login app goes to the MainActivity. When I click the back button i get this warning.

```
W/ActivityManager: Duplicate finish request for ActivityRecord
```

And when I start the app again LoginActivity is called again.

After successful login I call

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
```

The problem is only in the release build.

Comment: did you override onBackPressed() in your activity?

Comment: Yes. In Login Activity I've used this.     @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        this.finish();
    }

Answer (score 2):

If this is not related to back press, maybe you have more than one finish() call from different places. Just check if activity is finishing or not, if yes then skip the 2nd call.

```
if (!YourActivity.this.isFinishing()) {
    finish(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code causes calling the **onDestroy()** method  twice.

If your back button only triggers finish, change your `onBackPressed()` to this, remove `super.onBackPressed();`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}
```

Comment: I've updated the onBackPressed(), but the issue still there. If I run the build directly from the IDE, it works good. Issue occurs in the release build.

Comment: @user1382802 You must be calling/triggering onDestroy() on somewhere wrong to get this error log. Check your other overridden methods and finish(); codes. For example, never call finish(); inside onPause()

Comment: No. I'm calling finish() in onBackPressed(). There is no finish() in onPause() or onDestroy()

Comment: Also when I force close the app start again, its working fine.